# SQL Count of same country, same name, same age for people with same last name (e.g smith)

Tags: sql, count, duplicates, teradata

I need your advice.

we have the below table

Name of table: PEOPLE (i know bad name for example :-) )

```
ID       | firstname | age | country
1        | George    | 20  | US
1        | George    | 20  | GB
2        | Jim       | 20  | FR
2        | Jim       | 21  | FR
```

i need to see the below result, so for same ID counts of values

```
ID | firstnamecnt | agecnt | countrycnt
1  | 2            | 2      | 1
2  | 2            | 1      | 2
```

I hope I explained well :-)

Thanks and regards,
Alex

Comment: your  sample   .. and your expected   are not clear  try add a coherent and clear data sample ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant firstname. Here is one way

```
select id, 
       count(*) - count(distinct firstname) + 1 as firstnamecnt,
       count(*) - count(distinct age) + 1 as agecnt,
       count(*) - count(distinct country) + 1 as countrycnt
from people
group by id;
```

[**DEMO**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/HhCn5zL5ycpodn2xg1Wc7/0)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.. many thanks Isildur